# How to read predict() result in Tensorflowjs using a SavedModel

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow.js, efficientnet

Code using `tfjs-node`:

```
const model = await tf.node.loadSavedModel(modelPath);
const data = fs.readFileSync(imgPath);
const tfimage = tf.node.decodeImage(data, 3);
const expanded = tfimage.expandDims(0);
const result = model.predict(expanded);
console.log(result);
for (r of result) {
   console.log(r.dataSync());
}
```

Output:

```
(8) [Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor]
Float32Array(100) [48700, 48563, 48779, 48779, 49041, 48779, ...]
Float32Array(400) [0.10901492834091187, 0.18931034207344055, 0.9181075692176819, 0.8344497084617615, ...]
Float32Array(100) [61, 88, 65, 84, 67, 51, 62, 20, 59, 9, 18, ...]
Float32Array(9000) [0.009332209825515747, 0.003941178321838379, 0.0005068182945251465, 0.001926332712173462, 0.0020033419132232666, 0.000742495059967041, 0.022082984447479248, 0.0032682716846466064, 0.05071520805358887, 0.000018596649169921875, ...]
Float32Array(100) [0.6730095148086548, 0.1356855034828186, 0.12674063444137573, 0.12360832095146179, 0.10837388038635254, 0.10075071454048157, ...]
Float32Array(1) [100]
Float32Array(196416) [0.738592267036438, 0.4373246729373932, 0.738592267036438, 0.546840488910675, -0.010780575685203075, 0.00041256844997406006, 0.03478313609957695, 0.11279871314764023, -0.0504981130361557, -0.11237315833568573, 0.02907072752714157, 0.06638012826442719, 0.001794634386897087, 0.0009463857859373093, ...]
Float32Array(4419360) [0.0564018189907074, 0.016801774501800537, 0.025803595781326294, 0.011671125888824463, 0.014013528823852539, 0.008442580699920654, ...]
```

How do I read the predict() response for object detection? I was expecting a dictionary with `num_detections`, `detection_boxes`, `detection_classes`, etc. as described [here](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/d0/1).

I also tried using `tf.execute()`, but it throws me the following error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: execute() of TFSavedModel is not supported yet`.

I'm using `efficientdet/d0` downloaded from [here](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/d0/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download the tensor using `dataSync()` it just keeps the value. If you wanted the object with a description of each of the results without the tensors you would just have to `console.log(result)`. Then you expand the result from your log in the browsers console it should return something like this:

```
Tensor {
  "dataId": Object {},
  "dtype": "float32",
  "id": 160213,
  "isDisposedInternal": false,
  "kept": false,
  "rankType": "2",
  "scopeId": 365032,
  "shape": Array [
    1,
    3,
  ],
  "size": 3,
  "strides": Array [
    3,
  ],
}
```

The output of your `console.log(result)` contains `8 tensors` within it which shows that it is correct. You are looping over each of the results and each of the outputs should follow this format :

```
['num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_classes', 'detection_scores', 'raw_detection_boxes', 'raw_detection_scores, 'detection_anchor_indices', 'detection_multiclass_scores']
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you! Some considerations: the output tensors in the array were in a different order (you can find the right order using `getMetaGraphsFromSavedModel()` or looking for the matching shapes of the tensors). For example, `detection_anchor_indices` was the first one. Afterwards, I had to process the result by hand, e.g. doing `const scoreN = result[4].dataSync()[N]`, and then normalize all the data in an array, find the class names in a json, draw the boxes on the image, export the image, etc. Now I can see the results visually :D Thank you again

Comment: can you please expand your original answer with a code snipet of how you normalized all the data in an array and found the class names? I only need to feed my model an image and get as an output the detection result in text. I followed this to train a custom object detector model https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html

Comment: @user007 oh wait so the array is actually from the official documentation I think. If you go [here](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/d0/1) under outputs it mentions it.

Comment: hey again. Thank you for the link. I understood what each tensor in the output refers to, but I don't know how to convert and associcate those numbers to a response in this format: detectedObjects = [{object: 'cat', score: 70%}]. Any idea on how I can achieve that? @ernewston mentioned he normalised the data and found the class names. and I was wondering how to find the class names from those numbers in 'detection_classes' and the correct scores in 'detection_scores'

Comment: If I remember well, I iterated using an index to get each value from each array, and then made an array of "prettier" objects having "class_id", "class_name", "score", etc. To get the class name, I had a json file that mapped a class id with a name. Something like a list that is shown here: https://tech.amikelive.com/node-718/what-object-categories-labels-are-in-coco-dataset/.